# How would I make a button apply a universal selector to the whole html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a button element with the intention of making it color the entire text of the document white when clicked. How would I do this? I have this so far:

```html
<input type="image" id="btn" onclick="changeColor()" src=https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/eye-3-xxl.png>

<script>
  function changeColor(*) {
    .style.changeColor = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When applying styles with JS you can always use classes and css to manage the style and use JavaScript to toggle the class.

In this case you can achieve this by adding a class to the body and define the style with a regular css class.

```js
<script>

function changeUniversalStyle() {
  document.body.classList.add('universal-style');
}

</script>
```

```css
body.universal-style * {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<h1> Universal style </h1>

<button onclick="changeUniversalStyle()"> Toggle universal style </button
```

Comment: Have to add `!important` to override default css

Comment: ok, looks p good. where would I add the css styling? into an external css file or can it be on the page?

Comment: Its a good practice to have a general css style, but if you dont have a lot of styles you can just add the css to the `head` of the page. `<head> <style> ... body.universal-style *... </style>  </head>`

Answer (score -2):

For your issue, use `jQuery`. It will be very easy to achieve what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('*').css('color','red');  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is h1</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<section>This is a section.</section>

<button>Click Me</button>
```